# Is this behavior of `std::unique_ptr` expected?

Tags: c++, memory-management, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have a project that I've been working on that uses polymorphism to implement the encoding of objects via overriding an `encode` function.

Now, this project has been using pointers to implement the polymorphic behavior. Since my application was relatively new, I decided that it wouldn't be too difficult to switch from regular raw pointers into smart pointers, as they would automatically manage memory.

In one of my functions, I return an `std::unique_ptr`. After returning the smart pointer, I immediately wanted to cast the underlying raw pointer. So an oversimplification of what was happening would look something like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<something> do_something() {
    return std::unique_ptr<something>(new something());
}

void caller() {
    auto output = static_cast<another*>(do_something().get());
    // Do something with output...
}
```

I knew that `std::unique_ptr` doesn't have a copy constructor, as it can only be "owned" once at any given instant. Implementing a copy constructor would allow for the creation of a duplicate pointer, going against this principle. If my understanding is correct, the following code initializes `B` using the move constructor, and does not copy `A`:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> get_a() {
    std::unique_ptr<int> A(new int);
    return A;
}

void get_b() {
   auto B = get_a();
}
```

This was exactly the behavior that I wanted. However, in my example, the program crashes around half of the time. The other half of the time, it *appears* to work, but the contents of the underlying pointer are just plain garbage. (I'm suspecting that this was undefined behavior, and `get()` was only sometimes returning a readable address.)

Now, after some thought, I came to the conclusion that if `B` was indeed being initialized via a move constructor, `B` itself would have to **not** be a temporary. However, in my first example, the result of `do_something()` is a temporary, and I'm **move constructing it**! So I decided to stop inlining the call to `do_something()`, and then I immediately got the expected behavior! Every time I used `get()` on a temporary object, the results were unpredictable and simply wrong.

**My question is:**

Should I be expecting this behavior of `unique_ptr`? If so, how is this behavior documented? (More specifically, was my first example undefined behavior?) And are there any alternatives (`shared_ptr`, maybe?) that would allow me to inline the function call and still get the expected results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is summarised in your statement *"they would automatically manage memory"*.

Your `unique_ptr` (post-move) is a temporary that goes out of scope immediately after the declaration of `output`, taking the dynamically-allocated `int` with it and leaving `output` dangling.

Temporary. *Temporary*! So-named for good reason…

This behaviour is "documented" in many, many places: storing a pointer to an object that has gone out of scope is a really bad idea, and henceforth *using* that pointer is just outright broken (yes, it's UB).

You can't hack around this by switching to other smart pointers, no: stop "inlining" the function call (and stop using this terminology; that's not what "inlining" means) and ensure that the object exists for as long as you want to access it through a pointer.

```
auto ptr    = do_something();
auto output = static_cast<another*>(ptr.get());
```

Comment: So to clarify, what's happening is that I'm extracting the underlying pointer from a temporary, and then the temporary is calling it's destructor, thereby making my pointer garbage?

Comment: @ra1nmaster: Yes. Just like `int* ptr = 0; { int x = 5; ptr = &x; } /* now try to use ptr; whoops! */` Nothing magic and nothing specific to either `unique_ptr` or move semantics.

Comment: Thank you, it makes so much more sense now.